# Reference Data is lost from Form when Validation Fails (Spring 3 MVC)

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I am new to Spring
I am having a page addContact,in that I am getting dropDown Data from Database in the following way

```
@RequestMapping("/addContact")
 public ModelAndView registerContact(@ModelAttribute Contact contact) {
 List<ContactType> contactTypeList = contactdao.getContactTypeList();
 Map<Integer,String> contactTypeSelect = new LinkedHashMap<Integer,String>();
 Iterator<ContactType> iterator = contactTypeList.iterator();
while (iterator.hasNext()) {
    ContactType ct = iterator.next();
    contactTypeSelect.put(ct.getContactTypeId(),ct.getContactTypeName());
}
Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
map.put("contactTypeSelect", contactTypeSelect);
 return new ModelAndView("addContact", "map", map);
}
```

Now to Insert the Data into Database, I am having following method,

```
@RequestMapping("/insert")
public String insertData(@Valid Contact contact, BindingResult result,    HttpServletRequest request )  {
  if (result.hasErrors()) {
        return "addContact";
    } 
  else {
      HttpSession session = request.getSession();
      session.setAttribute("path", request.getSession().getServletContext().getRealPath("/WEB-INF"));
      if (contact != null){
            contactService.insertData(contact,request);
      }
      return "redirect:/getList";
  }
```

}

When the validation fails, the drop down data is lost (which is obvious), what is the correct way of achieving the validation.

Comment: Why are you converting the list into a map?! Why not let spring do that by using the spring form tags?! (Use the `form:select` or `form:options` tag for that.) And why are you adding a map to a map, that seems as an unnecessary overhead...

Comment: M. Deinum, I understand your point, If I directly Bind List<ContactType> to my form:select , it shows me the Object Representation (com.apnabetul.domain.ContactType@1389f7e1) ,How can I display id and Name ?

Comment: I think I got it, this works <form:options items="${contactTypeSelect}" itemLabel="contactTypeName" itemValue="contactTypeId"/>

Comment: I modified my answer to include this...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Create a method annotated with `@ModelAttribute` which loads the reference data. This method will be called before each `@RequestMapping` method.

```
@ModelAttribute("contactTypeSelect")
public List<ContactType> registerContact() {
    return contactdao.getContactTypeList();
}
```

In your form you can use the `<form:select ../>` tag to render the `itemValue` and `itemLabel`.

```
<form:select items="${contactTypeSelect}" itemLabel="contactTypeName" itemValue="contactTypeId" />
```

With this you can refactor your `addContact` method to the following

```
@RequestMapping("/addContact")
public String registerContact(@ModelAttribute Contact contact) {
    return "addContact";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You lose the drop down data because you're not adding in the contact map in the insertData method.  Pull out the code where you grab the contact data into a separate (private) method and use it in the result.hasErrors() if block as such:

```
if (result.hasErrors()) {
   return new ModelAndView("addContact", "map", map);
}
```

Also, I strongly suggest adding a method to the @RequestMapping annotation as such:

```
@RequestMapping("/insert", method=RequestMethod.POST)
```

This keeps people from making GET calls to this method.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. In that case I will have to change the return type of the insert method to ModelAndView, and Also in the else part I would have to get all necessary Data for getList View to return ModelAndView

Comment: Indeed, but I figure you would know how to do that.  If this works for you please mark it as the 'Accepted Answer'